# How to change the Exif Interface tag TIMESTAMP?

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried many times to solve the issue I am having with the Exif Interface. What I am trying to do is to change the time stamp tag to it's regular time, but I don't think I am doing it correctly despite that is a GPS tag, also known as `ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP`, here is the code I am thinking of using, the result displays as `null` in the Logcat and ignore the rest of the information that will be displayed on it, any ideas on how to make it properly ? Thank you in advance:
Logcat:

```
D/CameraOrientationUtil: getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=90, sourceRotationDegrees=90, isOppositeFacing=true, result=0
D/ImageCapture: Send image capture request [current, pending] = [0, 1]
D/ImageCapture: issueTakePicture
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@bf66d7f[id=0]} Issue capture request
D/CaptureSession: Issuing capture request.
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=114
D/ViewRootImpl@c84535c[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{1b6a7eb V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} TM=true MM=false
V/Toast: Text: Пбра in android.widget.Toast$TN@cb14948
D/ViewRootImpl@c84535c[Toast]: Relayout returned: old=[0,32][1280,800] new=[538,656][742,715] result=0x7 surface={true 3728250880} changed=true
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [204x59]-format:1
D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xca143520, 0xde389808
D/ViewRootImpl@c84535c[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=[538,656][742,715] ci=[0,0][0,0] vi=[0,0][0,0] or=2
I/Model: SM-T395
I/Manufacturer: samsung
I/Artist: CadIS
I/Date Stamp: 2021:10:06
I/Time Stamp: null
I/Latitude: 42/1,43/1,87135600/10000000
I/Latitude Reference: N
I/Longitude: 23/1,15/1,49287600/10000000
I/Longitude Reference: E
I/Orientation: 0
I/Image Direction: null
```

```
private lateinit var outputDirectory: File

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   /**Checking for all permissions to be granted through method,
         *if so it will start the camera, if not checks for a request with permissions and request code**/
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

// Making a variable, connecting to the button and setting up a listener to initiate taking a photo through a method
        val imageCaptureBtn = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.camera_capture_button)
        imageCaptureBtn.setOnClickListener {
            takePhoto()
        }

   // Connecting the late init variable with a new method to get output directory
        outputDirectory = outputDirectoryFolder()
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
}

/**This method provides when clicked to take a photo and save it to the specified directory**/
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private fun takePhoto() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Обработва се ..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        //val fileName = SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US).format(System.currentTimeMillis()).substring(1)
        // Creating a file that combined the directory and the name of that image file as JPEG format
        val photoFile = File(outputDirectory, "IMG-${SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH).format(System.currentTimeMillis())}.jpg")

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@CameraActivity, "Обработването се провали!, $exc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                }

                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                   val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                   val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri" Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                   Log.d(TAG, msg)

val exif = ExifInterface(photoFile)
                    checkExifData(exif)
}

private fun checkExifData(exifInterface: ExifInterface) {
saveExifData(exifInterface) // This method will save any custom/changed data in it and will re-use the tag as an identifier.
   val exifTimeStamp = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP)

   Log.i(TAG, "$exifTimeStamp")
}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private fun saveExifData(exifInterface: ExifInterface) {
        try {
   val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP, timeStamp)
exifInterface.saveAttributes()//This will save any written data that the tags are included.
} catch (e: Exception) {
     e.printStackTrace()
     Log.e("Error", "$e")
     Toast.makeText(this, "$e", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

photoFile - This it the File variable that will use the file's exif and metadata change on the image JPEG format.

outputDirectory - Recasted variable that is used on a different method. Using the method is making a folder "Pictures" in Internal Storage(`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`), then another File() type making another folder "CadIS for Android" within "Pictures".

FILENAME_FORMAT - This is casted in a `companion object` in order to rename the file to the date and time format:

Comment: `the result displays as null in the Logcat` Pretty unclear what is null. Or what you consider to be the result. Shouldnt you post logcat lines to make all clear?

Comment: @blackapps It's added on the top.

Comment: Sorry, you made your code that complicated that i still do not know what you do. For instance: `Log.i(TAG, "$exifTimeStamp")
}` What is logged? I nowhere see it

Comment: `val exifTimeStamp = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP)

   Log.i(TAG, "$exifTimeStamp")` Place these lines too before saveExifData().  Any difference? And place them in saveExifData(). And where are all that log lines logged that you posted?

Comment: @blackapps No, it's still shows the result: ```I/Time Stamp: null``` and I am sorry if I made it visually difficult and complicated code, that's how my brain works and how I work, but that is a different subject and I apologize for making it difficult.

Comment: If the exif header does not contain an ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP to begin with.. if you get already null.. then how would you change or add it?

Comment: `What I am trying to do is to change the time stamp tag to it's regular time` Confusing sentence. You are not trying to change time stamp but gps time stamp.

Comment: To explain it again, I just want to change the GPS time stamp, and replace that time stamp with the time that is now.